# jquery Card item click event doesn't work

Tags: html, jquery, card

I wrote HTML tags with jquery for cards. I want each item to be displayed after clicking the button on each card. But with the code I wrote, the click event of other buttons is not called and only the button event of the first card is called.
Here is HTML code:

```
<body>
<p class="app-title p-5">Products</p>
<div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-md-4 g-4 m-5" id="productList"></div>
<script>
    getProducts();
</script>
</body>
```

jquery functions:

```
function showProducList(product) {
return `
<div id="col" class="col">
    <div class="card h-100">
        <h5 id="Id" class="productId card-title bg-primary text-white p-3 text-center">${product.id}</h5>
        <div class="card-body">
             <p id="name" class="productName card-text"><b>${product.name}</b></p>
             <p id="price" class="productPrice card-text"><b>${product.price}</b></p>
             <button id="btnPrint" class="btnPrint">print</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
`;}
```

getProducts() function sends product model to showProducList function and its Ok.
but the problem is this click event for card button is not working!

```
$("#productList").click(function() {
$("#btnPrint").click(function() {
    console.log("clicked");
        var productId= $(this).parent().prevAll("h5").text();
        var productName= $(this).siblings(".productName").text();
        var productPrice= $(this).siblings(".productPrice").text();
        window.localStorage.setItem("productId", productId);
        window.localStorage.setItem("productName", productName);
        window.localStorage.setItem("productPrice", productPrice);
        showPrintPreview();        
});});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you need `$("#btnPrint").click(function() { }` inside the `$("#productList").click(function() {`

The `btnPrint` element is rendering from `showProducList` function and this is not available to execute the javascript code.

You can fix it in a couple of ways.

**1. Use [$(document).ready(function{})](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)**

Move your code inside the `$(document).ready(function{})`

```
$(document).ready(function{
  $("#productList").click(function() {
    $("#btnPrint").click(function() {
      console.log("clicked");        
    });
  });
});
```

**2. Bind click event with document**

```
$(document).on("click", "#productList", function() {
  $(document).on("click", "#btnPrint", function() {
    console.log("clicked");        
  });
});
```

**Edited**

Assuming you have multiple buttons with the same Id. Tn this case, better to use button class `btnPrint`.

```
$(document).ready(function{
  $(".btnPrint").click(function() {
    console.log("clicked");        
  });
});
```

OR

```
$(document).on("click", ".btnPrint", function() {
  console.log("clicked");        
});
```

Hope you find this helpful.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. It's work for other buttons on card. but when the page is loaded, button click doesn't work at the first time, I have to click on the button twice.

Comment: And also when I click other buttons on other cards, just the value of the first card is returned.

Comment: @tara1367 - I think there is some implementation issue. If you are loading more than one buttons then you should provide unique id or use class in click. I'm editing the answer.

Comment: Thank you so much. you save my day. good luck.

Comment: @tara1367 - sounds great! you may select it as a right answer and/or upvote. Happy coding :)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I selected it as the right answer. but sorry I need at least 15 reputations to cast a vot. good luck.